# How does one use pdf@strcmp in the pdftexcmds package?

Tags: pdftex, conditionals, strings

I am trying to compare two strings with pdf@strcmp but I get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pdf 
            @strcmp{abc}{abc}
l.6     \section{\pdf@strcmp{abc}{abc}}
```

Here is what I am trying to run:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\begin{document}
    \section{\pdf@strcmp{abc}{abc}}
\end{document}
```

I was expecting to see something like 0 being output. From what I understand the strcmp returns 0 if the strings are equal, -1 if A < B and 1 otherwise. I've installed the `oberdiek` package so I believe I have the dependencies I need.

This seems simple but I must be missing something obvious so, how do I make this comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for using a macro with `@` in its name you've to use `\makeatletter` before that to change the at sign cat code.

The following code will work:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
    \section{\pdf@strcmp{abc}{abc}}
\makeatother    
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. You also forgot to put `\` before the command.

Comment: Ah, so simple, I believe the `\` disappeared when I simplified the code. I've edited to make it reflect what was actually the problem (the missing \makeatletter).